# String interpolation while inserting multiple elements into xml from inside a for loop

Tags: lxml, lxml.objectify

For some reason, I found it difficult to generate an XML file by inserting multiple nodes from inside a `for` loop. The following does achieve that, but a couple of questions remain.

Given a list of dictionaries

```
dict_list = [{'x': 'abc', 'y': 'efg'}, \
            {'x': 'hij', 'y': 'klm'}]
```

I can use `objectify()` to generate the desired xml:

```
from lxml import etree, objectify
end_game = etree.XML('<final_root/>')

E = objectify.ElementMaker(annotate=False)
tmp_root = E.entry
for d in dict_list:
    att_values = [val for val in d.values()]    
    doc = tmp_root(   
        x = att_values[0],
        y = att_values[1]
     )    
    end_game.append(doc)
print(etree.tostring(end_game, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

Output, as desired:

```
<final_root>
  <entry x="abc" y="efg"/>
  <entry x="hij" y="klm"/>
</final_root>
```

The problem is that I need to hardwire the attribute names `x` and `y` into the loop. Attempting to use string interpolation fails. For instance:

```
for d in dict_list:
     att_items = [item for item in d.items()] 
        doc = tmp_root(   
            att_items[0][0] = att_items[0][1],
            att_items[1][0] = att_items[1][1]
         )
```

raises

> SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Same error is raised using f-strings (`'f'{att_items[0][0]}' = att_items[0][1]`), or format (`{}.format(att_items[0][0]) = att_items[0][1]`).

So, the obvious question: is there a way to avoid having to manually insert attribute names? Alternatively: Is it possible to duplicate the outcome (and maybe avoid the issue) using `lxml.etree` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [etree Elements carry attributes as a dict](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-carry-attributes-as-a-dict), you should be able to just pass in the dict when constructing the Element...

```py
from lxml import etree

end_game = etree.XML('<final_root/>')

dict_list = [{'x': 'abc', 'y': 'efg'},
             {'x': 'hij', 'y': 'klm'}]

for meta in dict_list:
    end_game.append(etree.Element('item', meta))

print(etree.tostring(end_game, pretty_print=True).decode())
```

printed output...

```xml
<final_root>
  <item x="abc" y="efg"/>
  <item x="hij" y="klm"/>
</final_root>
```

Comment: Well, I'll be damned! It never occurred to me to use that property of Element to construct one from a dictionary... Live and learn! Thank you, kind sir.